# How to add new site to Apache-based Ubuntu server by using shell script, call by PHP?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, php, apache2

I have Unmanaged Apache-based Ubuntu VPS, I want to add new domain by using  shell script, call by PHP script ?

I can do this directly easily, see this http://www.servermom.org/how-to-add-new-site-into-your-apache-based-ubuntu-server/272/

but i want to use automatic php script for all these functions, how can i do this ?

EDIT :: how to call shell script using PHP ?

Comment: I wish I could downvote this.

Comment: Why would you create a php script to execute system commands? You need to make a shell script with bash for this.

Comment: can i call shell script using PHP ? @xR34P3Rx

Comment: Yea you can but can you explain why you want to use php in your question? You need to explain what you are doing so we can better help and you won't get down voted.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx plz check updated question

Comment: But there's still a gap of missing info. Why php? Are you creating a website in php that functions like a control panel? Or you want to run the script manually on the server?

Comment: You should not do anything like this before you have studied all possible security implications of this. If you simply execute a script to modify system files, you are basically opening your system for black hat hackers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're up to and why you want to use PHP to execute system commands. But to do this in PHP, you just use `shell_exec();` and in quotes you write your command.

I believe it is more practical to automate most of those commands in the article via a shell script in BASH. Simply add each command to a `.sh` file with the shebang `#!/bin/bash`.  The only ones that will be tricky are the ones that require you to edit the config file manually.